# Database Design for Quarter and Fiscal Year

Tags: database-design

I have a self debate on how to design the quarter and the fiscal year in my mind.

The cases:

For some company the quarter could vary for different years, like:
2011
Quarter 1(Q1): 1/1-3/31
Q2: 4/1-6/30
Q3: 7/1-9/30
Q4: 10/1-12/31

But in 2012 the Quarter begin and end may change:
Q1: 1/1-**4/15**
Q2: **4/16-7/15**
Q3: **7/16-10/15**
Q4: **10/16**-12/31

So I come up two different solutions, but I don't know which is better.

**Solution 1:**

FiscalYear(year, fromDate, q1ToDate, q2ToDate, q3ToDate, toDate, otherColumns)

In this solution, all the quarter ends will be stored, everything is in the same table.

**Solution 2:**

FiscalYear(year, otherColumns)

Quarter(fiscalYearId, fromDate, toDate, quarter)

FiscalYear and Quarter has a 1 to 4 relationship.

**Thinking:**

What I can compare is that the **Solution 1** is good because we know that there will be 4 quarters for all the years. So the design is normalized actually.

However, **Solution 2** looks like more extendable. But you have to do some joins when retrieving the data.

What you guys think is better? What is your reason?

------Edit------

Environment:

Database: MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we had to deal with this problem, years ago, we came up with a solution that worked very well for us.  We built a table, let's call it Almanac, that had one row per date.  The date, expressed as a date, was the primary key for this table.

It had columns for various related time periods, such as Fiscal Year, Fiscal Quarter, and even Fiscal Month, which all varied from year to year.  It also had columns to indicate workdays, weekends, company holidays, etc. etc.  In short, all the features of the company calendar.

We then wrote a program to populate this table with about ten years worth of data.  All of the strange logic of the company calendar was built into this one program.

Later on, when we wanted to classify other events, such as a sale, or the results of a workshift, all we had to do was join with this table on date, and select the relevant columns.  Very, very easy.

And highly convenient for a reporting database.  You could crank out the same report by Fiscal Quarter, or Fiscal Year in a matter of minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head I like solution 2 because I think on the whole the sorts of queries I can imagine happening will be easier.  You may have a few cases where crosstabs become important but those strike me as rare.

Now you haven;t mentioned which database, and these may give additional options.  In PostgreSQL for example you have ranged types, which would allow you to do two things:

1. Ensure no two quarters overlap using EXCLUDE constraints and
2. Join a row containing a date to the including quarter using range operators.

Now if you are on a db without such capabilities then one advantage of your first model is that it ensures no overlap.  You could simulate that in your second one by assuming all quarters are sequential and that you can dispense with the start date (and look that up based on previous row, perhaps using window functions).

Comment: I will use mysql as the db. Thanks for your suggestion.